# Why does the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin repeatedly claim that I need to restart qgis?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have installed the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin several times, both through the plugin manager, and via a manual installation.

But it repeatedly tells me I have to restart QGIS? But restarting QGIS does not change a thing.

I read on this site that installing the SEXTANT plugin was necessary, but that did not solve the problem either.

So far I tried all possible steps. I upgraded python to the latest version (3.6.1), upgraded QGIS to the latest version (2.18).

By the way, since I installed the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin, I get a message that a mini-dump has been written, each time I close QGIS. I suspect this is related to the problem of getting the desired plugin running, but I have no clue what to do with it?

Ultimately I want to download Sentinel-2 imagery in QGIS, any suggestion on alternative plugins therefore are also welcome?

Comment: Are you using the plugin just to browse and download - if so, as an alternative I prefer Remote Pixel: https://remotepixel.ca/projects/satellitesearch.html. It does not enable you to atmospherically correct the imagery though

Comment: Thomas Groen, which operating system are you using and what process did you follow in installing QGIS? That info may help someone to provide a solution to your issue.